# List all DNS's (FQDN's) in an Azure Resource Group, Tenant, or Subscription

Tags: azure, dns, fqdn

## Background

I tried to launch a container and associate a DNS name with it upon creation.  The first time I tried, it failed because it said that the DNS name was already used. Specifically, it said:

```
The DNS name label 'miketest' in container group 'mike-portal-test' not available. Try using a different label.
```

I realized that this DNS name is global, using the FQDN of `miketest.westeurope.azurecontainer.io`, so that was obviously taken.  I quickly solved the problem by choosing a less boring test name.

## Problem

But it got me wondering: how can I see if I have left any "lingering" FQDNs / DNS names out there in my resource group (or subscription or tenant)?  I could not find a way to list the DNS names that I have made.

I found this in the [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-cli#list-record-sets):

```
az network dns record-set list --resource-group myresourcegroup --zone-name contoso.com
```

But it requires a `zone-name` and it only allows privately created zone names, so that I cannot pass the zone `westeurope.azurecontainer.io`. An attempt to use the previous command using the zone name `westeurope.azurecontainer.io` yielded the following error:

```
ResourceNotFoundError: Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'westeurope.azurecontainer.io' not found.
```

How can I list what DNS's I have created?  Can I assume that any resources that I delete which have DNS names associated automatically have their DNS names deleted upon deletion of the resource?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I list what DNS's I have created?

It's difficult to answer this question because FQDN is global. The name must be unique within the Azure region where you create the container instance. Your container will be publicly reachable at `<dns-name-label>.<region>.azurecontainer.io.` It not only exists on your resources but also other services in the global DNS by using container suffix `.westeurope.azurecontainer.io`. You can't list other customer resources using the same container suffix here.

> Can I assume that any resources that I delete which have DNS names
> associated automatically have their DNS names deleted upon deletion of
> the resource?

Yes. The Azure DNS name above will be deleted automatically if the resource is deleted.

Comment: Thank you, Nancy!  Yes, I do understand where my container is reachable, and that the FQDN is globally shared.  But still, there must be **some** documentation tracing that the FQDN belongs to Azure, and that Azure is letting me (my subscription) use it.  So I do not understand why Azure cannot provide me a list of FQDNs that I have created in my subscription.  :(  But I do appreciate your confirmation on the auto-deletion.  This makes it simpler than, for instance, managing gateways and VNets.

Comment: Add [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal) said that `The name must be unique within the Azure region where you create the container instance.` The DNS name is provided by azure DNS, you will have a fixed DNS suffix. If you want custom FQDN, you can create A or CNAME dns records that map to the Azure FQDN in your DNS provider. You will have full control of your DNS records and custom domain for ACI.

Comment: "But still, there must be some documentation tracing that the FQDN belongs to Azure and that Azure is letting me (my subscription) use it. ". A fully qualified domain name (FQDN) represents a domain name of a host or IP address(es). The FQDN is like a domain name. The DNS works globally not just Azure let you use it. Azure just provide the different DNS subdomain for different Azure resources, see [this FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-addresses#dns-hostname-resolution)for a public IP resource.

Comment: Do you still have any questions?

Comment: Hi @Nancy, yes, I do, but it sounds like they are unanswerable.  I just wanted to know how to get a list of all FQDNs that I might have created and which are still "alive", even for resources that auto-generated the FQDN, like an ACI.  But since they *should* always cleanly remove themselves *and* there is no way for me to know the answer, I will just assume all works out OK.

Comment: The remaining numbers of FQDNs will be (X-Y). X represents any [1-9][a-z] characters, the Y represents what you have the name of your ACI within one region.